# unstorage drivers issue? [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath ‘./drivers/fs’ is not defined by “exports” in

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a group project.

Started with nuxt boilerplate from `npx create-nuxt-app OUR_PROJECT` and for everyone it works except one who it is getting this issue

```
 Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath ‘./drivers/fs’ is not defined by “exports” in   │
   │   /Users/ONE_USER/OUR_PROJECT/node_modules/unstorage/package.json imported from                       │
   │   /Users/ONE_USER/OUR_PROJECT/node_modules/@nuxt/content/dist/module.mjs
```

anyone have any idea what this is or how to fix it? we have tried cloning from scratch, we have tried installing xcode / command line tools, no one else has this issue.

from `node_modules/unstorage/package.json`

```json
...,
"exports": {
    "./drivers/*": {
      "import": "./dist/drivers/*.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/drivers/*.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/drivers/*.d.ts"
    },
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs"
    },
    "./server": {
      "import": "./dist/server.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/server.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/server.d.ts"
    }
  },
...
```

is the same in everyone's files.

EDITS:

note: brand new MacBook Air

NPM Debug log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ ‘/usr/local/bin/node’, ‘/usr/local/bin/npm’, ‘run’, ‘dev’ ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ ‘predev’, ‘dev’, ‘postdev’ ]
5 info lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~predev: OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ONE_USER/OUR_PROJECT/node_modules/.bin:/Users/ONE_USER/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /Users/ONE_USER/OUR_PROJECT
10 silly lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ ‘-c’, ‘nuxt’ ]
11 silly lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
12 info lifecycle OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack   at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack   at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack   at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/ONE_USER/f22-backup
16 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
17 verbose argv “/usr/local/bin/node” “/usr/local/bin/npm” “run” “dev”
18 verbose node v14.3.0
19 verbose npm v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the OUR_PROJECT@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Try to use the LTS of node: v16. Also, does everybody have the same issue? I recommend checking the related package'S Github issues/discussions if there is not a similar issue already.

Comment: @kissu no, just this one person. We googled a bunch, found many similar things but none matching this.